# Botones supuespuesto en un JinternalFrame

Tags: java, java-swing

Cree un Jframe, que llama a un JInternalFrame que llama a otro JinternalFrame.
El problema : Los botones/tablas que hay en el primer JinternalFrame se superponen al segundo jif.
Gracias
Codigo:

```java
            private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent                          evt) {  

//Instancio el primer JinternalFrame desde mi JFrame

        ArticulosForm af = new ArticulosForm(); 

        this.VentanaPrincipal.add(af);  //VentanaPrincipal es un jdesktop
        af.show();
        try {

        af.setMaximum(true);

        } catch(PropertyVetoException e) {}

         private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        //Instancio al segundo JInternalFrame desde mi primer JinternfalFrame
        NuevoArticulo nv = new NuevoArticulo();

        this.VentanaArticulo.add(nv); // VentanaArticulo es un jpanel

        centrarVentana(nv); // Metodo que utilizo para centrar la ventana con  la propiedad Dimension
```

Comment: pone codigo porfavor para poder ayudarte

Comment: coloca ese codigo en tu pregunta porfavor

Comment: Pertenezco al eslabon mas bajo de la evolucion, disculpe el escracho

Comment: Hola, estas utilizando un JPanel o no? no esta muy claro tu código amigo, intenta mejorarlo un poquito mas

Comment: Si perdon, ahi aclare que son cada cosa

Answer (score 0):

Al final cambie el diseño, y cree otro JFrame en vez de utilizar el primer JInternalFrame, ahora puedo hacer lo que queria sin que se superpongan los botones, por si alguien le pasa lo mismo